# Play/Pause Dynamic Flot Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am very new to jQuery so any help is welcome. I have a dynamic graph made with jQuery and Flot that is pretty much the same as the following example:
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html

The only changes I made to the code were cosmetic. However, I would like to add functionality to pause and play the updates made to the graph based on a button click. I thought adding some conditionals to the update section of code:

```
    function update() {

        plot.setData([getRandomData()]);

        // Since the axes don't change, we don't need to call plot.setupGrid()

        plot.draw();
        setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
    }

    update();
```

might accomplish this but I wouldn't know what functions to employ. How could I go about writing this pause/play functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pause the updates with minimal changes to the original, just add a state variable in the `update()` function:

```
function update() {
    if (!paused) {
        plot.setData([getRandomData()]);
        plot.draw();
    }
    setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
}
```

You can improve the efficiency by only running the timer as needed, but the code above should work.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Jeeze I'd better go back and review the the basics. I didn't even think to use booleans.